# Intercept UITextField touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate, uicontrolevents

I would like to intercept a touch on a `UITextField`, for instance when I first load it I give it a `@selector()` to load a different method instead of the `delegate` stuff?

This is my attempt:

```
descriptionText = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 25.0, infoView.frame.size.width - 20, 100.0)];
    descriptionText.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    descriptionText.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    descriptionText.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentTop;
    descriptionText.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [descriptionText addTarget:self action:@selector(loadInfoView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    descriptionText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15];
    // show view
    [infoView addSubview:descriptionText];
```

However when I debug the method:

```
- (void)loadInfoView
{
    NSLog(@"load other view here");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in the `forControlEvents:`: try `UIControlEventEditingDidBegin`

```
[descriptionText addTarget:self action:@selector(loadInfoView:) UIControlEventEditingDidBegin];
```

Your `@selector(loadInfoView:)` is also wrong if you have `- (void)loadInfoView`

or `@selector(loadInfoView:)` and `- (void)loadInfoView: (id) sender`
or `@selector(loadInfoView)` and `- (void)loadInfoView`

However, why you don't use the `UITextFieldDelegate`?

**.m**

```
@interface ViewController () <UITextFieldDelegate>

    @property (strong, nonatomic) UITextField *descriptionText;

@end
```

**Remember to:**

```
self.descriptionText.delegate = self;
```

**Then:**

```
-(void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == self.descriptionText)
    {
        [self loadInfoView];
    }

}
```

**Keyboard**:

If you don't want to show the keyboard you need to add a `[descriptionText resignFirstResponder];`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can get actions to be called on a text field on touch like you want.

If that doesn't work, why don't you attach a tap gesture recognizer to your text field?

Comment: OFC you can get actions called with ControlEvent: UIControlEventEditingDidBegin or with UITextFieldDelegate